# Why xmodmap effect do not last

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

In Elementary OS Loki, if I run the command
    xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Multi_key"
it works nicely, and I can use the left Windows key as Composer. But the effect do not last. If a lock the screen and when around for a while (cannot say how long, but say half an hour), when I come back I have to run xmodmap again.

Why?

Comment: Found a better way to do it with the answer by @clodal here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that running `xmodmap` works until the system is restarted. In my case it helped to add it to System Settings > Applications > Startup. The paths in the command should be absolute, otherwise they will not be recognized correctly:

`/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/{your_user_name}/.Xmodmap`

I realize that your problem is different, but this solution might help. You might also consider adding this command to `.profile` in your home directory (although it didn't work in my case).